# How to combine (OR) two expression trees

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have two expression trees of type : `Expression<Func<string, bool>>` and I would like to obtain a single Expression that will do the OR of the two expressions (passing the same string parameter to both expressions)
Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking here, perhaps you can explain why your asking?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`PredicateBuilder` from LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to do this. For example:

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> e1 = …;
Expression<Func<string, bool>> e2 = …;
Expression<Func<string, bool>> combined = e1.Or(e2).Expand();
```

Comment: It works, but as I am going to use it with EF in a LinqToEntities query I can not use Invoke there.

Comment: @Dave That's what the `Expand()` is there for, it takes care of the `Invoke`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try combining them in a `Expression.Lambda` expression and then using `Expression.Or` to check if one of them is true.

Here is an example:

```
Expression<Func<Car, bool>> theCarIsRed = c1 => c1.Color == "Red";
Expression<Func<Car, bool>> theCarIsCheap = c2 => c2.Price < 10.0;
Expression<Func<Car, bool>> theCarIsRedOrCheap = Expression.Lambda<Func<Car, bool>>(
    Expression.Or(theCarIsRed.Body, theCarIsCheap.Body), theCarIsRed.Parameters.Single());
var query = carQuery.Where(theCarIsRedOrCheap);
```

Maybe you can get more info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx)

Comment: That doesn't work, because the parameter used in the body of `theCarIsCheap` no longer exists in the resulting expression. You need to use the long way with the ExpressionVisitor.