# How to OR combine two Expression for EF core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I already had a look at the following question, but it didn't gian much traction and the problem remains unsolved.
[How to combine (OR) two expression trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597201/how-to-combine-or-two-expression-trees)

How do you `or`-concatenate two `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.

let's consider the simplest case:

```
var fulltext = "some text";

private Expression<Func<User, bool>> FulltextSearch(string fulltext) {

    Expression<Func<User, bool>> left = t => t.Name.Contains(fulltext)
    Expression<Func<User, bool>> right = t => t.Description.Contains(fulltext)
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Task, bool>>(Expression.Or(left.Body, right.Body), left.Parameters);
}

var users = dbContext.Users
    .Where(FulltextSearch("name xy"))
    .ToList();
```

*this is a simplified example!*

This ends in an error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<User>()
    .Where(t => t.Name.Contains(__fulltext_0) | t.Description.Contains(__fulltext_0))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'...
```

But you can easily write this query like this and it works:

```
var users = dbContext.Users
    .Where(u => u.Name.Contains(fulltext) || u.Description.Contains(fulltext))
    .ToList()
```

So how do you combine two Expression<Func<T,bool>> into one such that ef core can translate it into SQL?

Comment: And what problem(s) did you have using the solutions provided on the question you linked?

Answer (score 2):

`Expression.Or` will translate to a **bitwise** `OR`operation (c# `|`  Operator). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.or?view=net-5.0
This will lead to the `InvalidOperationException` since it cannot be translated to SQL.

`Expression.OrElse` will translate to a **logical** `OR`operation. (c# `||` operator) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.orelse?view=net-5.0
This translates to SQL's `OR` operator and is the one you want to use when combining the expressions.

Comment: Can you connect the dots a bit more?  Are you saying one version of these will work, but the other will not?

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, `OrElse` will work, `Or` will not work.

Comment: Even with OrElse it doesn't work.. The solution was to write a custom `ExpressionVisitor` as the other duplicate suggested. Somehow I just couldn't find it via google...

Comment: This has been such a life saver! Thank you!